# text fade in-out with multiple blocks of text using css only

Tags: css-animations, delay, fade, keyframe

I have 3 blocks of text. I want block 1 to fade in and show for 3 seconds and then to fade out. As soon as its opacity reaches 0, I want text block 2 to fade in and be visible for 3 seconds... same with text block 3. I thought I could achieve this by assigning the am animation to all 3 and different `animation-delay` for each, but they all seem to eventually display in unison:

```
<main>
  <h2>Text block 1</h2>
  <h2>Text block 2</h2>
  <h2>Text block 3</h2>
</main>



@keyframes textFader {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

h2 {
    animation-name: textFader;
    animation-duration: 12s;   
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;        
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
h2:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
h2:last-of-type {
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
```

I know it can be done with 3 separate animations:

```
   @keyframes textFader1 {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  8% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  25% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  33% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes textFader2 {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  34% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  42% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  59% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  67% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes textFader3 {
    0% {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    66% {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    83% {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
    91% {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
    100% {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
  }
```

But this it's kind of a management/editing nightmare for 1, much less 3 (especially with more complex keyframes) - there's gotta be a better way?

I know this can be done quite-easily with JavaScript, but I need a CSS-only solution. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: textFader;
  animation-duration: 18s; /* <---{ 6sec * num(H2) = 18sec } */
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

h2:first-of-type { animation-delay: 0s; }
h2:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 6s; }
h2:last-of-type { animation-delay: 12s; }

@keyframes textFader {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  } /* fade-in */
  11% {
    opacity: 1;
  } /* show */
  22% {
    opacity: 1;
  } /* fade-out */
  33% { /* <-------------------{ 100% / num(H2) = 33% } */
    opacity: 0;
  } /* waiting for the finish animation of other blocks */
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Text block 1</h2>
  <h2>Text block 2</h2>
  <h2>Text block 3</h2>
</main>
```